# Steps to debug products not showing in frontend?

Tags: magento2

None of the products are showing up in storefront categories. Not working in any category or in any storeview. The product is visible by its direct url.

I think there is something going wrong with the database, indexers or Elastic Search (or a combination of one or more of those.)

I am looking for a structured way to debug (or collect relevant info) why products are not showing op in frontend. What is the best approach?

- Magento 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

First place to check would be the log files, found in var/log from your Magento root. `exception.log` / `system.log` / `debug.log` best bets if it's an error.

I'd also open dev tools in your browser. Check the console tab, see if there are any errors when loading your listing page. I'd also check the network tab in your browsers dev tools. Open the network tab, load the page, click on your listing page request and see if an error is returned in the response - or check for any problematic error codes in subsequent requests.